# How to know which kind of adverb in NLP Parts of Speech (POS) tagging?

Tags: natural-language-processing

There are 4 kinds of adverbs :

- Adverbs of Manner. For example, slowly, quietly
- Adverbs of Place. For example, there, far
- Adverbs of Frequency. For example, everyday, often
- Adverbs of Time. For example, now, first, early

nltk, spacy and textblob only tag a token as an adverb without specifying which kind it is.

Are there any libraries which tag including the type of adverb?

Answer (score 2):

Generally POS taggers only use broad categories, especially if they work statistically: the more fine-grained the tagset is, the more training data you need. And unless there are differences in the distribution, the accuracy of the tagger would not be improved by adding more categories, eg

> *I ran* [*there*/*fast*/*often*/*early*].

all work -- so nothing is gained by having subcategories of adverbs.

I suggest the easiest solution for this would be to have a list of adverbs by category, and simply look them up *after* the tagging. Just pick all words tagged as adverbs and check if they are in your list. Unless there are ambiguities (ie some adverbs can belong to multiple categories) it should be very straight forward, and would also work with any tagger/tagset that marks adverbials.

You might have to consult a grammar book to get a list of adverbial classes, but that again should be easy to do.